# How use Dependency Injection for a library which use PSR-0

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have a problem with DI in **service.yml** file, my file contains this code:

```
...
...
AppBundle\Providers\BuilderInterface:
    class: AppBundle\Providers\Builder
    arguments:
        $service: '@Google_Service_Bigquery'
        $job: '@Google_Service_Bigquery_Job'
        $jobConfExtract: @Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfigurationExtract'
        $jobConf: '@Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfiguration'
...
...
```

but, Symfony 3.4 show me this error:

```
Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Providers\Builder": argument "$service" of method "__construct()" references class "Google_Service_Bigquery" but no such service exists. It cannot be auto-registered because it is from a different root namespace.
```

I open **composer.json** in Google library:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Google_Service_": "src"
    }
}
```

They use PSR-0 to autoload classes, but in Symfony 3 it not work.

How can I fix this trouble ?

Comment: Sorry to say that, but your class names suck a little :( one cannot tell what `Builder` does. How about `GoogleSdkBuilder` next time?

Comment: This is not psr0 related.  If it were a question of autoloading then you would get a "class not found" exception.  See the answer below.

Comment: @emix its good idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register mentioned class as a service:

```
Google_Service_Bigquery: ~
```

This is an equivalent of:

```
Google_Service_Bigquery:
  class: Google_Service_Bigquery
```

then you can remove the line from the argument list as it will be auto-wired:

```
$service: '@Google_Service_Bigquery'
```